# Custom List duplicates last added element

Tags: java

I have made a custom list and added two elements to my list.
when I try to display these two elements, It only displays the last added element twice. I am a beginner in java, I cant seems to find why my list only contains last added item in duplicate !

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Home {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int length = 2;
    String[] machineName = { "BMW", "AUDI" };

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++){
        setMachineDetails(machineName[i]);
        System.out.println("Machine Details No. : " + i + " SET");
    }

    System.out.println("\n\nDisplaying List contents\n\n");

    System.out.println("Size of List : " + MachineDetails_List.serverData.size() + "\n\n");

    for (MachineDetails model : MachineDetails_List.serverData){
        System.out.println("MachineDetails Name : " + model.getMachineName());
    }
}

private static void setMachineDetails(String name) {

    MachineDetails md = new MachineDetails();
    md.setMachineName(name);
    MachineDetails_List.serverData.add(md);
    System.out.println("Machine Name : " + name + " SET");
 }
}

class MachineDetails {
    public static String MACHINE_NAME;

    public static String getMachineName() {
        return MACHINE_NAME;
    }

    public static void setMachineName(String machineName) {
        MACHINE_NAME = machineName;
     }
}

class MachineDetails_List {

    public static List<MachineDetails> serverData = new ArrayList<MachineDetails>();

    public static List<MachineDetails> getServerData() {
        return serverData;
    }

    public static void setServerData(List<MachineDetails> serverData) {
    MachineDetails_List.serverData = serverData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MACHINE_NAME` don't need to be `static`. Since the field is static, all of the `MachineDetails` object's `MACHINE_NAME` will have same value.

Remove `static` keywords from `MachineDetails` class:

```
class MachineDetails {

    public String MACHINE_NAME;

    public String getMachineName() {
        return MACHINE_NAME;
    }

    public void setMachineName(String machineName) {
        MACHINE_NAME = machineName;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a freaking genius

Answer (score 0):

```
You should make list,variable to be non static.

public List<MachineDetails> serverData = new ArrayList<MachineDetails>();

class MachineDetails {

    public String MACHINE_NAME;

    public String getMachineName() {
        return MACHINE_NAME;
    }

    public void setMachineName(String machineName) {
        MACHINE_NAME = machineName;
    }
}
```